# How can I resolve an error using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic

When I execute the stored procedure, I receive the following error message.

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USP_History_Building, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 8]
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT * FROM EDB_Q217.dbo.POSTAL_ADDRESS PA WHERE PA.BUILDING_ID = ' to data type int.

I've tried slight changes to the code but none work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_History_Building] 

     @BUILDING int

AS 

DECLARE @quarterStart int = 2
DECLARE @quarterEnd int = 1
DECLARE @yearStart int = 17
DECLARE @yearEnd int = 19
DECLARE @BUILDING_ID int
DECLARE @year int
DECLARE @quarter int

DECLARE @quarterForDbName nvarchar(4)
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(max)

SET @year = @yearStart
SET @quarter = @quarterStart
SET @sqlStatement = ''
SET  @BUILDING_ID = @BUILDING


WHILE @year <= @yearEnd
BEGIN
WHILE ((@year < @yearEnd AND @quarter <= 4) OR (@year = @yearEnd AND 
@quarter <= @quarterEnd))

BEGIN
SET @quarterForDbName = 'Q' + CAST(@quarter AS nvarchar(1)) + 
CAST(@year AS nvarchar(2))

    SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + 
    'SELECT * FROM EDB_'+ @quarterForDbName +'.dbo.POSTAL_ADDRESS PA 
    WHERE PA.BUILDING_ID = ' + @BUILDING_ID


  SET @quarter = @quarter + 1  


   END

SET @quarter = 1
SET @year = @year + 1

END

PRINT @sqlStatement
EXEC (@sqlStatement)
```

The expected result is that a number of address fields are returned for the previous 8 quarters.

Comment: Use ' + CAST(@BUILDING_ID AS VARCHAR)

Comment: Super.  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_executesql` to pass parameters to code:

```
WHILE @year <= @yearEnd
BEGIN
    WHILE ((@year < @yearEnd AND @quarter <= 4) OR (@year = @yearEnd AND @quarter <= @quarterEnd))
    BEGIN
        SET @quarterForDbName = 'Q' + CAST(@quarter AS nvarchar(1)) + CAST(@year AS nvarchar(2));

        SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + '
SELECT *
FROM EDB_'+ @quarterForDbName +'.dbo.POSTAL_ADDRESS PA 
WHERE PA.BUILDING_ID = @BUILDING_ID
';
        SET @quarter = @quarter + 1 ; 
    END;
    SET @quarter = 1;
    SET @year = @year + 1;
END;
PRINT @sqlStatement
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement,
                   N'@BuildingId int',
                   @BuildingId=@BuildingId;
```

You cannot pass in the table name as a parameter, but you should pass in constant values using parameters.